# AngularJS - Running a funcion on false of ng-pattern

Tags: angularjs, validation, controller

I know that this issue has been mentioned before. Although I believe that this issue is slightly different.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18125777/angularjs-form-field-validation-using-javascript-function-without-directives)
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900308/angularjs-dynamic-ng-pattern-validation)

I have the following code

```
<textarea name="Text2" cols="40" rows="2" ng-model="pageModel.storeText" ng-pattern="/^(?:\d+(?:, *|))*\d+$/" class="form-control"></textarea>
<span ng-show="itemStoreForm.Text2.$error.pattern">ERROR</span>
```

I need the ng-show in the span to initiate a function I have based in a controller:

```
$scope.storeError = function(){

    messageService.setMessage("messageContainer", "Please enter store numbers in correct format", "danger");
};
```

How can I call the function storeError()?

Comment: How about on `ngSubmit`?

Comment: Will a ngSubmit run on the detecting of bad user input according to the regex?

Comment: No, it will run once when you try to submit the form.

Comment: I am looking for something which will validate the text in a textarea on the fly

Answer (score 2):

If you can access the scope-object from your controller, try

```
$scope.$watch('itemStoreForm.Text2.$error', function(error) {
    if (error && error.pattern) {
        $scope.storeError();
    }
});
```

Since the FormController is published on `$scope` via name, it should be accessible for a watch-function.

Comment: Unfortunately this only runs on load of the page, it doesn't react to the regex.