# Validating input in nAngular form using custom function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I know I can make Angular validate inputs against regex, so I can allow/deny certain values. But is there a way to validate an input value against a custom function?

For example, say that the input value is pushed in an array and I want to check if the value of the input is already in the array.

Also, I want to be able to mark the input as `invalid` or `required`, the same way Angular would do it if I was using plain regex.

Comment: ng-change? If the value changes do something

Comment: @Fals How would I set the state to `invalid` from there?

Comment: You could use ui-validate as per [this stack overflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18133694/4682556)